# "log has private access" error when using Slf4j annotation and Lombok in IntelliJ

Tags: java, slf4j, lombok, intellij-14

I'm using Lombok to add logging to my Java applications. I've been using this for some time, but since I upgraded my IDE from IntelliJ 13 Community edition to 14 Ultimate, I get the following compile errors (using maven):

```
error: log has private access in SesameServer
```

This error originates in a subclass of `SesameServer`:

```
@Slf4j
public class AnnotatorServices extends SesameServer {

  @Override
  protected void initialiseRDFStoreManager(Series<Parameter> parameters) throws RepositoryConfigException, RepositoryException {
      log.info("<< ------ Annotator Services ------- >>");
  }
}
```

Of course `SesameServer` also uses the `@Slf4j` annotation to add logging. The `@Slf4j` annotation adds the line:

```
 private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(SesameServer.class);
```

to the class in which it is used (both `SesameServer` and `AnnotatorServices` where `SesameServer.class` is of course replaced by `AnnotatorServices.class`).
Apparently the compiler thinks I want to use the `log` variable from `SesameServer` instead of `AnnotatorServices` (both classes have variables with the same name).

How can I prevent this problem, i.e. that the `SesameServer.log` is used instead of `AnnotatorServices.log`?

Comment: ```AnnotatorServices.this.log```

Comment: rebuild, this should work *as is*.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex Unfortunately no.

Comment: @RC. Normally I'm using maven for compilation. If I do a rebuild in IntelliJ I still get the same errors, but with som extra information:  Warning:(23, 8) java: Can't initialize javac processor due to (most likely) a class loader problem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/code/TypeTags
   at lombok.javac.Javac.<clinit>(Javac.java:104)
   at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleGetter.<clinit>(HandleGetter.java:294)...
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ...

Comment: My advise, check for update (intellij and lombok plugin), clear all intellij caches, restart intellij and let it rebuild, you might have something bad in your caches.

Comment: @RC did not work unfortunately. But it definitely is a IntelliJ problem. I can compile without errors or warning on the command line.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=451 I bet :)

Comment: @RC Yes that was it! Many thanks ;D - we used an older version of lombok because of some other issues, but upgrading to the newest version did solve this problem.

Comment: Google Code link above is now at https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/524

Answer (score 8):

*NOTE: This still comes up for anyone else googling this error message; so adding my fix hope this helps.*

I had a similar issue after reopening a project from `pom.xml`.

Since my parent class `SesameServer` was already built in a different module and used a dependency; when I compiled my `AnnotatorServices` I also saw the `error: log has private access in SesameServer`

---

To fix it I just had to turn on Annotation Processing for the module containing `AnnotatorServices`.

In IntelliJ Community 2017.1.6 the check box was found under:

1. File -> Settings
2. **"Build, Execution Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors"**
3. Tick the **"Enable annotation processing"**

Answer (score 3):

Following steps worked for me

1. Install `Lombok Plugin` in Settings=>plugins under Marketplace search for Lombok and install.
2. Then in `IntelliJ Community 2017.1.6` go to File->Invalidate Caches/ Restart and click on both.

Did the trick for me. All the best.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your subclass is also annotated properly with @Slf4j.

Answer (score 0):

Update your lombok plugin. Sometimes idea does not display the new updates so goto settings => plugins and search for "lombok"
Click "update" and restart idea

Comment: I tried it, but still problem persists. Any other ideas please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would extend https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693518/2252417...

Make sure you have a proper import for the @Slf4j in the class where you experience the error.

It also happened to me when I used `import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j;`. It needed to be replaced by `import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;`

Issue was introduced by applying the 1st import suggestion by the Intellij :)